# Transit js code to newly opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Sorry for my Bad language skills.
I rewrite this question 10 times. But still hard to express my question...

**My Question**

I hope to know how to transit js code to newly opened window.

**My situation**

I have opening new window event and window resizing event js code

```
    //When user click <a id="new-window">new window</a>, new window come up.

       $('#new-window').click(function (){


            var videoWidth = $(window).width()/2;
            var videoHeight = videoWidth/5*3;

            var windowWidth = videoWidth + 20;
            var windowHeight = videoHeight + 20;

            var w =  window.open('', '', 'width=' + windowWidth + ', height=' + windowHeight);
```

//$(#video) is the 
                var html = $("#video").clone().attr({
                    "width" : videoWidth,
                    "height" : videoHeight
                });

```
            $(w.document.body).html(html);

                event.preventDefault();

        }); 

        function videoFit() {
            var videoScreen = $(window).width();
            $('#video').css({'width': videoScreen, 'height':videoScreen/5 * 3});    
        }

        $( window ).resize(function(){
            videoFit();
        });
```

But when I open developTool(chrome) in new window, there are no js files and css files which I put in the parent window.

following code just adjusted to parent window.

Is there any solution to transit js code?

Thank you for read my questions.

Comment: You CANNOT transfer, or communicate JavaScript between windows.  This is an inherent, built in security feature of JavaScript.  Imagine I was able to transmit things like Login information from one window to another .. Or credit card info?  This is why browsers don't allow this sort of feature.  If you want to transfer information between windows, you'll have to do it via `SESSIONS` on the `Server Side`

Comment: @Zak Oh I see. I get new infomation from you. Thanks you for answer my question. I try to find other method. I find a clue that it is possilble to controling child window in parent window!